# scikit-learn TruncatedSVD's explained variance ratio not in descending order

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, svd

The TruncatedSVD's explained variance ratio is not in descending order, unlike sklearn's PCA. I looked at the source code and it seems they use different way of calculating the explained variance ratio:

[TruncatedSVD](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py):

```
U, Sigma, VT = randomized_svd(X, self.n_components,
                              n_iter=self.n_iter,
                              random_state=random_state)
X_transformed = np.dot(U, np.diag(Sigma))
self.explained_variance_ = exp_var = np.var(X_transformed, axis=0)
if sp.issparse(X):
    _, full_var = mean_variance_axis(X, axis=0)
    full_var = full_var.sum()
else:
    full_var = np.var(X, axis=0).sum()
self.explained_variance_ratio_ = exp_var / full_var
```

[PCA](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py):

```
U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / n_samples
explained_variance_ratio_ = (explained_variance_ /
                             explained_variance_.sum())
```

`PCA` uses sigma to directly calculate the explained_variance and since sigma is in descending order, the explained_variance is also in the descending order. On the other hand, `TruncatedSVD` uses the variance of the columns of transformed matrix to calculate the explained_variance and therefore the variances are not necessarily in descending order.

Does this mean that I need to sort the `explained_variance_ratio` from `TruncatedSVD` first in order to find the top k principle components?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to sort `explianed_variance_ratio`, output itself would be sorted and contains only the `n_component` number of values.
From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis):

> TruncatedSVD implements a variant of singular value decomposition
>   (SVD) that only computes the  largest singular values, where *k* is a
>   user-specified parameter.

X_transformed contains the decomposition using only k components.

The [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) would give you an idea

```
>>> from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
>>> from sklearn.random_projection import sparse_random_matrix
>>> X = sparse_random_matrix(100, 100, density=0.01, random_state=42)
>>> svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5, n_iter=7, random_state=42)
>>> svd.fit(X)  
TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', n_components=5, n_iter=7,
        random_state=42, tol=0.0)
>>> print(svd.explained_variance_ratio_)  
[0.0606... 0.0584... 0.0497... 0.0434... 0.0372...]
>>> print(svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum())  
0.249...
>>> print(svd.singular_values_)  
[2.5841... 2.5245... 2.3201... 2.1753... 2.0443...]
```

Comment: I think they might have fixed the issue in randomized_svd, I will dig out the dataset I used that caused the problem 2 years ago and test it again.

Comment: For me the ratios also arent sorted in decreasing order and do not sum up to 1, which is not my understanding of ratios! I use sklearn version 0.21.3