# sci-kit learn TruncatedSVD explained_variance_ratio_ not in descending order?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, variance

This question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299061/scikit-learn-truncatedsvds-explained-variance-ratio-not-in-descending-order), which however remains unanswered at the time of writing.

Why is the `explained_variance_ratio_` from `TruncatedSVD` not in descending order like it would be from `PCA`? In my experience it seems that the first element of the list is always the lowest, and then at the second element the value jumps up and then goes in descending order from there. Why is `explained_variance_ratio_[0]` <  `explained_variance_ratio_[1]` ( > `explained_variance_ratio_[2]` > `explained_variance_ratio_[3]` ...)? Does this mean the second "component" actually explains the most variance (not the first)?

Code to reproduce behavior:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

n_components = 50
X_test = np.random.rand(50,100)

model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=n_components, algorithm = 'randomized')
model.fit_transform(X_test)
model.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Comment: PCA is accomplished (depending on the package used) by performing SVD on mean centered data.
Maybe the discussion below will help.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition

Answer (score 0):

If you scale the data first, then I think the explained variance ratios will be in descending order:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

n_components = 50
X_test = np.random.rand(50,100)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=n_components, algorithm = 'randomized')
model.fit_transform(X_test)
model.explained_variance_ratio_
```