# Why Sklearn TruncatedSVD's explained variance ratios are not in descending order?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd

Why `Sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD`'s explained variance ratios are not ordered by singular values?

My code is below:

```
X = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]])
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=4)
svd.fit(X4)
print(svd.explained_variance_ratio_)
print(svd.singular_values_)
```

and the results:

```
[0.17693405 0.46600983 0.21738089 0.13967523]
[3.1918354  2.39740372 1.83127499 1.30808033]
```

I heard that a singular value means how much the component can explain data, so I think explained variance ratios also are followed by the order of singular values.
But the ratios are not ordered by descending order.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard that a singular value means how much the component can explain data

This holds for PCA, but it is not exactly true for (truncated) SVD; quoting from a relevant [Github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3047) back in the day when an `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute was not even available for `TruncatedSVD` (2014 - emphasis mine):

> preserving the variance is not the exact objective function of truncated SVD **without centering**

So, the singular values themselves are indeed sorted in descending order, but this does not hold necessarily for the corresponding explained variance ratios if the data are not **centered**.

But if we do center the data before, then the explained variance ratios come out sorted in descending order indeed, in correspondence with the singular values themselves:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

sc = StandardScaler()
Xs = sc.fit_transform(X) # X data from the question here

svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=4)
svd.fit(Xs)

print(svd.explained_variance_ratio_)
print(svd.singular_values_)
```

Result:

```
[4.60479851e-01 3.77856541e-01 1.61663608e-01 8.13905807e-66]
[5.07807756e+00 4.59999633e+00 3.00884730e+00 8.21430014e-17]
```

For the mathematical & computational differences between centered and non-centered data in PCA & SVD calculations, see [How does centering make a difference in PCA (for SVD and eigen decomposition)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition)

---

Regarding the use of `TruncatedSVD` itself, here is user ogrisel (scikit-learn contributor) in a relevant answer in [Difference between scikit-learn implementations of PCA and TruncatedSVD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239481/difference-between-scikit-learn-implementations-of-pca-and-truncatedsvd):

> In practice `TruncatedSVD` is useful on large sparse datasets which cannot be centered without making the memory usage explode.

So, it's not exactly clear why you have selected to use `TruncatedSVD` here, but, if you don't have a too-large dataset that causes memory issues, I guess you should revert to PCA instead.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @장동엽 You are very welcome; notice that the question had been asked several times in the past (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299061/scikit-learn-truncatedsvds-explained-variance-ratio-not-in-descending-order) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411576/sci-kit-learn-truncatedsvd-explained-variance-ratio-not-in-descending-order)), but without a satisfactory answer so far ;)